# Node leaves the kubernetes cluster randomly

Tags: azure, kubernetes

I created kubernetes cluster (v1.2.1) in azure environment using the tool [here](https://github.com/weaveworks/weave-kubernetes-coreos-azure). I have 3 etcd nodes, 5 kube nodes (minions) and 1 kube master.

With the current configuration I'm facing issue where minion leaves the cluster randomly after few hours. Upon some debugging, docker daemon itself did not start on that node.

Error message I see when ssh'g to the bad node :

```
CoreOS stable (899.15.0)
Update Strategy: No Reboots
Failed Units: 5
  docker.service
  install-kubernetes.service
  install-weave.service
  locksmithd.service
  docker.socket
```

`$ kubectl get nodes` shows node status as NotReady and `$kubectl get events` shows weave API error 500 for pod scheduled on that node.

For some of the time restarting the node works but often times it does not. Can anyone help me debug this issue or propose some resolution or pointers ?

$ kubectl describe node kube-03

```
Name:           kube-03
Labels:         kubernetes.io/hostname=kube-03
CreationTimestamp:  Wed, 13 Apr 2016 02:23:02 +0530
Phase:          
Conditions:
  Type      Status  LastHeartbeatTime           LastTransitionTime          Reason      Message
  ────      ──────  ─────────────────           ──────────────────          ──────      ───────
  OutOfDisk     False   Wed, 13 Apr 2016 21:37:04 +0530     Wed, 13 Apr 2016 18:29:01 +0530     KubeletHasSufficientDisk    kubelet has sufficient disk space available
  Ready     False   Wed, 13 Apr 2016 21:37:04 +0530     Wed, 13 Apr 2016 18:29:01 +0530     KubeletNotReady         container runtime is down
Addresses:  172.18.0.20,172.18.0.20
Capacity:
 cpu:       4
 memory:    28815788Ki
 pods:      110
System Info:
 Machine ID:            8ab8c56a9b72435981be3ca65285a00e
 System UUID:           DBAD108F-9CEC-5548-BB66-22618928D4DA
 Boot ID:           cf27687a-0149-4c40-8f42-db7c4268e6b1
 Kernel Version:        4.3.6-coreos
 OS Image:          CoreOS 899.15.0
 Container Runtime Version: docker://Unknown
 Kubelet Version:       v1.2.1
 Kube-Proxy Version:        v1.2.1
ExternalID:         kube-03
Non-terminated Pods:        (0 in total)
  Namespace         Name        CPU Requests    CPU Limits  Memory Requests Memory Limits
  ─────────         ────        ────────────    ──────────  ─────────────── ─────────────
Allocated resources:
  (Total limits may be over 100%, i.e., overcommitted. More info: http://releases.k8s.io/HEAD/docs/user-guide/compute-resources.md)
  CPU Requests  CPU Limits  Memory Requests Memory Limits
  ────────────  ──────────  ─────────────── ─────────────
  0 (0%)    0 (0%)      0 (0%)      0 (0%)
No events.
```

Comment: `kubectl describe node <bad_node_name>` may give you a reason why the node went unready. If not, your best bet is to start with the kubelet logs. SSH into the bad node, and look at `/var/log/kubelet.log` (start at the end).

Comment: It seems like the problem is with docker, not kubelet. You may want to check 1) whether docker is running on the node, and 2) docker logs to see what went wrong.

Comment: Updated the description above with the `kubectl describe node <bad_node_name>` output

Comment: @Yu-JuHong : I verified that docker is not running and neither I can see the log files from docker containers on healthy nodes. Probably some docker configuration ? 

@TimSt.Clair : I don;t have `/var/log/kubelet.log` file on any of the node in the cluster.

Comment: Your node provisioning did not succeed based on the "failed units" You showed. I am not familiar with your setup, but try `sudo journalctl -u [unit]` to  see why those services failed.

Comment: Issue was with the command that creates link for kubectl; `/bin/ln -s /opt/kubernetes/server/bin/kubectl /opt/bin/`. Also there was issue with docker restart; it was not able to release the allocated ports. I had to delete the docker networks folder as a resolution. Hope it never happens again. This issues are very bad for production environment.

Comment: Not sure what the first issue is, but you should probably filing the issue against weave-kubernetes-coreos-azure. For the second issue, what version of docker do you use and what exactly the error messages were? We've had some problems with the docker 1.9 and had to modify our babysitter daemon script ensure a clean restart.